# oracle ERROR: ORE-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle

I have tried to install oracle instant client_basic 12_1 on oracle 11g (11_1) in windows 7 x86 with approach of this document :http://www.dbatoolz.com/t/installing-oracle-instantclient-basic-and-instantclient-sqlplus-on-win32.html
but when I check the installation whit this command (`sqlplus user/pass@TNS_ALIAS`) I get error:

> ERROR:
>   ORE-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

what does this mean? how can I fix that?

Comment: can you use `tnsping` to resolve the alias?

Comment: There are a lot similar questions on SO. [Just search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+ORA-12154+win).